Google Sheets Translations
I am translating a google sheet from English to Italian (and other languages) I have got the translation working, but I need to restricted the translation to 200 characters per translation, due to Amazon rules.
where can I add the "re-write limit of 200 characters"? or something similar so it translates to no bigger than 200 characters.
I am currently using vlookup to reference the English data, I am getting the error of:
Wrong number of arguments to IFERROR. Expected between 1 and 2 arguments, but got 3 arguments.
Currently using this function:
iferror(GOOGLETRANSLATE(vlookup(A3,'Plytix Export'!A:X,10,false),"en","it"),"")


So your question is not about Google Translate, but is instead about an issue you're having with the wrong number of arguments to IFERROR()? If so, you should correct your title. If not, then you should remove the information about the problem with IFERROR() and instead ask about the problem with Google Translate.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kindly Edit the question and Write a title that summarizes the specific problem. Although the body of the question is understandable, which I believe is the reason why the post graduated from Staging Ground, the title itself still needs to be worked on.

You may use LEFT or MID to restricted the translation to 200 characters per translation.
Try this:
=IFERROR(LEFT(GOOGLETRANSLATE(VLOOKUP(A3, 'Plytix Export'!A:X, 10, FALSE), "en", "it"), 200), "")

OUTPUT

You may also try this:
=IFERROR(MID(GOOGLETRANSLATE(VLOOKUP(A3, 'Plytix Export'!A:X, 10, FALSE), "en", "it"), 1, 200), "")

OUTPUT

